# Parsing JSON from YouTube API

Tags: java, json, youtube-api

I have a URL: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/charlieissocoollike/uploads?alt=jsonc&v=2  which supplies JSON information on latest youtube uploads from a user.

I have written some code to parse this JSON data but I don't understand how JSON works and how to parse it in Java.

```
public void getVideoData() throws ClientProtocolException, JSONException, IOException {

    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(getVideoJSON().toString()).nextValue();
    //String query = object.getString("data");
    JSONArray locations = object.getJSONArray("data");
    output.setText(locations.getString(1));

}

public JSONObject getVideoJSON () throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    final String URL = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/charlieissocoollike/uploads?alt=jsonc&v=2";

    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());      
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);       
    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();           
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);          
        JSONArray VideoData = new JSONArray(data);      
        JSONObject video = VideoData.getJSONObject(0);  

        return video;           
}
```

How should I pull the video id, title and description from the JSON Data of each video object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. What you need is:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
JSONObject dataObject = json.getJSONObject("data"); // this is the "data": { } part
JSONArray items = dataObject.getJSONArray("items"); // this is the "items: [ ] part
```

Then you can traverse over each video:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject videoObject = items.getJSONObject(i); 
    String title = videoObject.getString("title");
    String videoId = videoObject.getString("id");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but would I insert this code into the getVideoJSON method, make it void and remove the getVideoData method ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with it. I don't know what you're attempting to do with the data, but this code should give you a general idea of how to get each videos title and id (and more) out of all the video results.

Answer (score 4):

In http://www.json.org/ has a parser implemented in JAVA.

Comment: Did you read the question and the code? OP is already using it. He only don't know how exactly to extract the properties using that JSON parser. Plus, "Java" isn't an acronym, so please don't yell it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using the official client library: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#Retrieving_user_activity_feeds

Comment: I have tried using the client libraries but I constantly get a VerifyError in com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaServices ? And have no clue what is wrong ?