# How to parse json data from youtube api

Tags: java, json, youtube-api

hey anyone please help me to parse this json,
 i am looking to get the title, publishedAt, thumbnail-medium, and the video id i just picked up json and i just cant seem to figure it how

is there any library to easily parse json data in android

```
{
"kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
"etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/tZ0XuLaM3U0kNd5fu8g8SBWXrNc\"",
"nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
"pageInfo": {
"totalResults": 575,
"resultsPerPage": 1
},
"items": [
{
"kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
"etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/7Z-xWmpBobcm6xZ1RTjzLbHnx0c\"",
"id": "UExhblJWbURLdVl2RmxjYmt1ZDhZd2VTNnhjc0x1cGpTby5BMjIxMjQ4MTYyMzQwNEYw",
"snippet": {
"publishedAt": "2016-10-03T12:20:10.000Z",
"channelId": "UC55LzMuR6ZeSpJMNCAfzb8w",
"title": "Cauvery Row : Affidavit filed by Attorney General Mukul Rohatgi to SC",
"description": "ಕಾವೇರಿ ವಿಚಾರವಾಗಿ ಕೊನೆಗೂ ಕೇಂದ್ರ ಸರ್ಕಾರ ರಾಜ್ಯದ ನೆರವಿಗೆ ಆಗಮಿಸಿದೆ. ಸದ್ಯಕ್ಕೆ ಕಾವೇರಿ ನೀರು ನಿರ್ವಹಣಾ ಮಂಡಳಿ ರಚನೆ ಸಾಧ್ಯವಿಲ್ಲ ಅಂತ ಅಟಾರ್ನಿ ಜನರಲ್\u200b\u200b ಮುಕುಲ್\u200b ರೋಹ್ಟಗಿ ಸುಪ್ರೀಂಗೆ ಅರ್ಜಿ ಸಲ್ಲಿಸಿದ್ದಾರೆ.",
"thumbnails": {
 "default": {
  "url": "htps://i.ytimg.com/vi/Zgvl_-0RcmI/default.jpg",
  "width": 120,
  "height": 90
 },
 "medium": {
  "url": "htps://i.ytimg.com/vi/Zgvl_-0RcmI/mqdefault.jpg",
  "width": 320,
  "height": 180
 },
 "high": {
  "url": "htps://i.ytimg.com/vi/Zgvl_-0RcmI/hqdefault.jpg",
  "width": 480,
  "height": 360
 },
 "standard": {
  "url": "htps://i.ytimg.com/vi/Zgvl_-0RcmI/sddefault.jpg",
  "width": 640,
  "height": 480
 }
},
"channelTitle": "Btv Kannada Ɩ ಬಿಟಿವಿ ಕನ್ನಡ",
"playlistId": "PLanRVmDKuYvFlcbkud8YweS6xcsLupjSo",
"position": 0,
"resourceId": {
 "kind": "youtube#video",
 "videoId": "Zgvl_-0RcmI"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON from YouTube API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652791/parsing-json-from-youtube-api)

Comment: @Rax Weber yes, am using java